# Next JS | getStaticPath

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, server-side

1. Do I need to use getStaticPaths if I'm not going to run the "next export" command?
2. Can I create a cache structure on the server side using getStaticProps and revalidate for the detail page (/user/1)? Or is there no alternative other than using SWR or getServerSideRender?
3. Isn't it redundant to get all the data again in the detail(/user/1) page?

Note: User detail page can be refreshed every 60 seconds. Instant update is not important.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.id },
  }))
  return { paths }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts/${params.id}`)
  const post = await res.json()
  return { props: { post } }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No . getStaticPaths is useful when it comes to statically generating lot's of pages incrementally .
2. Yes in next js you can use revalidate cache strategy only when you are generating static pages with getStaticProps like this :

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts/${params.id}`);
  const post = await res.json();
  // revalidate value is basically in seconds so here it will revalidate the 
  // data every 1 second only If there is an update to it .
  return { props: { post }  , revalidate : 1 }
}
```

3. You can use getStaticProps method with getStaticPaths to incrementally generate all pages you need and use pagination .